# UIScrollView zoomed with subviews gets different position after back from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

All,

I have a viewController with a ScrollView. On this scrollView, I have a UIImage as subview.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyblue_numbered_15x15_900x900.png"];
self.boardImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.boardImage.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};
[self.boardScrollView addSubview:self.boardImage];

self.boardScrollView.contentSize = image.size;
```

When I zoom, use home button and then call app again, everything is fine.

Now, I place an other subview on it by dragging the object to the scrollView:

```
- (void)myTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchPointScreen = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint touchPointImage  = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.boardImage];

 if (touchPointScreen.x > self.boardScrollView.frame.origin.x &&
     touchPointScreen.x < self.boardScrollView.frame.origin.x + self.boardScrollView.frame.size.width &&
     touchPointScreen.y > self.boardScrollView.frame.origin.y &&
     touchPointScreen.y < self.boardScrollView.frame.origin.y + self.boardScrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        self.tmpDragObject.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,60,60);

        [self.boardImage addSubview:self.tmpDragObject];
    }
  self.tmpDragObject = nil;
}
```

When I zoom, the subviews are also zoomed.

```
- (void)scrollViewDoubleTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
CGPoint pointInView = [recognizer locationInView:self.boardScrollView];

CGFloat newZoomScale = self.boardScrollView.zoomScale * 1.5f;
newZoomScale = MIN(newZoomScale, self.boardScrollView.maximumZoomScale);

if (newZoomScale != 1.0f) {  
    CGSize scrollViewSize = self.boardScrollView.bounds.size;

    CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale;
    CGFloat x = pointInView.x - (w / 2.0f);
    CGFloat y = pointInView.y - (h / 2.0f);

    CGRect rectToZoomTo = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

    [self.boardScrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomTo animated:YES];
}
```

**ISSUE:** When I use the home button and then call the app again, the app repositions the subviews of the ScrollView. So all subviews are replaced downwards, about the size of the tmpDragObject or the size of the navigation bar.

Why is this happening? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had to set the automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets on my view controller to NO.